# Mechanism for extensible conditional statement

Tags: c++, qt, compile-time, qt4.8, pre-compilation

I have these lines in my code:

```
//lines in mycode.c++
  QString str = "...some id...";

       if( str == "int")
           foo< int>()
  else if( str == "QString")
           foo< QString>()
       ...
```

I need to create a mechanism to include custom types in this conditional statement. So, any programmer can register his class and his implementation of *foo* templated function.

I imagine it like this:

```
//A.h -- custom class
class A { };

template< >
  void foo< A>() { ... };

DECL( A, "A"); //macro to declare class
```

I want conditional statement in **mycode.c++** that would automatically take in account declaration of class *A*, so it will have additional lines:

```
else if( str == "A")
    foo< A>()
```

I could have this effect like this:

```
//common.h
  void process_id( QString str) {
       if( str == "int")
           foo< int>()
  else if( str == "QString")
           foo< QString>()
       ...
  else if( str == "A") //this lines programmer put manually
           foo< A>();
  }

//mycode.c++
  #include "common.h"

  QString str = "some_id";

  process_id( str);
```

but what if programmer forgets to edit **common.h** file?

I thought, maybe to use C-macros system, or somehow Qt-precompilation. Is it possible?

Comment: Sure it is possible. However you need to be aware that at some point the programmer will have to give a list of possible strings and their result, so you will still have pretty much the same problem (although the syntax may be a tiny bit nicer).

Comment: Did you consider using a factory/map to dispatch the calls rather than `if/else`?

Comment: This feels all backwards to be.  Why use a giant `if` block when you can use dispatch?

Comment: @MarkB In my mycode.c++ I need to call function with template parameter decided from runtime variable. If I can do this without if/else -- that's ok.

Comment: @JohnDibling dispatch?

Comment: For example, your datatypes should be able to `foo` themselves, rahter than having to explicitly call a different `foo` for a specific datatype.

Comment: @JohnDibling I believe this want work for me. I serialize objects to strings and put them in DB. After I go back-process making deserialization. And at this moment I don't know what concrete type I put there. So I use ids to mark this strings and map them in runtime to generate proper class. This lines with *if* is from deserialization.

Comment: So `foo` is a factory function?  Then store numeric identifiers instead of strings, and implement a jump table (similar to @Barry's solution below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
void process_id(QString const & str) 
{
   auto it =  g_actions.find(str);
   if ( it != g_actions.end() )  
         (it->second)(); //invoke action
}
```

And the framework to support the above is implemented as:

```
 using action_t = std::function<void()>;

 std::map<QString, action_t>  g_actions; //map of actions!

#define VAR_NAME(x)       _ ## x
#define DEFINE_VAR(x)  VAR_NAME(x)
#define REGISTER(type) char DEFINE_VAR(__LINE__) = (g_actions[#type] = &foo<type>,0)
```

Now you could register any class as:

```
 //these lines can be at namespace level as well!
 REGISTER(A);
 REGISTER(B);
 REGISTER(C);
```

And then call `process_id()` as:

```
process_id("A"); //invoke foo<A>();
process_id("B"); //invoke foo<B>();
```

Hope that helps.

See [this online demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d30b5dff921765c).

Comment: I think **&foo<T>** must be **&foo<type>**. Should I make *g_actions* extern, or somethink like this?

Comment: @ValentinT.:  Yes. That's correct. Edited it, adding an online demo.

Comment: Thanks, I see that this works for C++11. Now trying to recreate it for 4.9.2 ( http://ideone.com/lG0sn1 ).

Comment: You need to use `DEFINE_VAR(__LINE__)` instead of `char _ ##__LINE__`.

Comment: Also `typedef void action_t( void);` defines a function-type, **not** a function-pointer type. Use `typedef void (*action_t)(void);`

Answer (score 3):

I would just create a vector of functors:

```
using ProcessFunc = std::function<bool(const QString&)>;
std::vector<ProcessFunc> ids;

void process_id(QString str) {
    for (ProcessFunc& f : ids) {
        if (f(str)) {
            break;
        }
    }

    // or...
    std::any_of(ids.begin(), ids.end(), [&](const ProcessFunc& f){
        return f(str);
    });
}
```

Where you just provide a method to append a new such `ProcessFunc`:

```
template <typename T>
void register_class(const QString& name) {
    ids.emplace_back([=](const QString& str) {
        if (str == name) {
            foo<T>();
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Your example specifically would be:

```
register_class<int>("int");
register_class<QString>("QString");
register_class<A>("A");
```

Which I suppose you could turn into a macro if you really wanted to.

Comment: And **ids** vector would be global?

Comment: @ValentinT. It needs to be accessible to wherever `process_id` lives. If that's a class, then a private member would make the most sense.